# Google Play REST API returning error 500 while replying to review

Tags: android, api, google-play

I am trying to reply to a review made to my android app through the API by calling this:

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/*packageName*/reviews/*reviewId*:reply?access_token=*access_token*

Package name, reviewId and access_token are all correct and I have gotten list of reviews using the same credentials.

I get error code 500 which is an internal server error. Does it mean the error is from Google API's side? Can anybody please suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the following link which says "You can retrieve only the reviews that users have created or modified within the last week. If you want to retrieve all reviews for your app since the beginning of time, you can download your reviews as a CSV file using the Google Play Console."

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews#retrieving_reviews

It says while retrieving reviews but I guess it also goes for while replying to a review. When I tried to reply to a review made more than 7 days ago, I get the 500 error. However, I am able to successfully reply to reviews made within a week.